# How to get explicit form of polar cone?

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-cone

I'm asked about a question to find the explicit form of polar cone of $C=\{x:x=Ap,p\geq 0\}$. But I can only write out by definition $C^*=\{y:y^TAp\leq 0,p\geq 0\}$. But can the expression be more explicit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It easy to see that the polar is
$$
C^* = \{y : A^Ty \leq 0 \}
$$

By definition,

$$
C^* = \{y : y^T A p \leq 0, p \geq 0\}
$$

Take $p = e_i$, the unit vector with $1$ at coordinate $i$ for some $i$. Then we have

$$
y^T (A)_i \leq 0 \Leftrightarrow (A^T y)_i \leq 0, \forall i
$$

Therefore, we just proved that $C^* \subseteq \{ y: A^T y \leq 0 \}$. Now, we will prove that $\{y: A^T y \leq 0\} \subseteq C^*$. Take any such $y$: it is easy to see that

$$
y^T A p = p^T \underbrace{(A^T y)}_{\triangleq q} = p^T q = 
\sum_i p_i q_i
$$

but we know that $p_i \geq 0, q_i = (A^T y)_i \leq 0, \forall i$ by the above. Therefore, $y^T A p \leq 0$, concluding that
$\{y : A^T y \leq 0\} = C^*$.

Comment: Thanks! It helps a lot

Comment: @JiachuanDeng: No worries! Consider marking the answer as accepted if it resolved your problem.

Comment: What if my cone is given in the form $C=\left\{y:A^\top y \leq 0\right\}$ and I want to calculate/compute $C^\ast$?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps another way, $C$ is the set of all linear combinations of columns of $A$ with positive coefficients.